# Remotely checking HTTP Status with cURL

Tags: php, curl, while-loop

I am trying to generate rows based on the code below. Would someone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't get the error reporting to work where I am. Are you able to use cURL within while loops?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_entries))

  if ($row['active'] == "y") {

    $ch = curl_init($row['url']);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    // $retcode > 400 -> not found, $retcode = 200, found.
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($retcode == '[4-5][0-9][0-9]'){
        echo "<tr class=\"bad"\"><td><a href=\"" . $row['code'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">". $row['code'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['url'] . "</td><td>" . $row['requester'] . "</td></tr>\n\n";

    } else if ($retcode == '[2-3][0-9][0-9]'){
        echo "<tr class=\"good"\"><td><a href=\"" . $row['code'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">". $row['code'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['url'] . "</td><td>" . $row['requester'] . "</td></tr>\n\n";

    } else {
        echo "<tr class=\"inactive\"><td>". $row['code'] . "</td><td>" . $row['url'] . "</td><td>" . $row['requester'] . "</td></tr>\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `$retcode == '[4-5][0-9][0-9]'` mean?

Comment: Please add more information, in what way is this not working as expected? Also, numerical comparisons on `$retcode` would be preferable, and it might be sane(er) to call `curl_close()` after the `if-elsif-else` block, although that is almost certainly not the cause of your error.

Comment: I keep getting a 500 error because they don't have error reporting turned on here. So I'm not exactly sure, also I'm a PHP newbie. It's supposed to be colouring rows as working, broken and inactive.

Comment: “I keep getting a 500 error because they don't have error reporting turned on here.” - You should try a solution like MAMP or XAMPP (google them) for running the code on your local machine, you can't be expected to develop software when you can't see the error messages, this is insane.

Comment: I had XAMMP but it got wiped out somehow during an exercise.

Comment: Invest the time to bring it back, otherwise you're shooting in the dark! (Trust me, I've been developing a long time, and having the code on your machine, running, displaying good error messages is the single most important thing about software development)

Comment: Thanks I got the XAMPP back up and running. Now I'm getting error on pages that run fine on the server but not on local host.

Answer (score 3):

You should use numerical comparisons on your `$retcode` variable

```
if($retcode >= 400 && $retcode <= 599) {
  // Code for 400> status here
} else if ($retcode >= 200 && $retcode <= 399) {
  // Code for 200-300 status Here
} else {
  // Fall through case here
}
```

Your code isn't correctly comparing the result code to the string, (which you are trying to treat as a regular expression).

Numerical comparisons will be faster, easier to read, and a more secure solution.

Comment: Thanks I changed it. Unfortunately it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a regex in the comparison. `$retcode` will just be an integer. It should just be something like:

`if ($retcode == 400){`

You can use `preg_match()` on `$retcode` if you want many codes to execute the same block of your if, although it may be better to use a `switch` or greater than less than, i.e. `if($retcode >= 400 && $retcode <= 599){`.

Comment: please see my answer, he should check for `$retcode` being within a range to replicate the intended bahaviour of his non-working regular expression.

Comment: @Beaks Your answer was quicker and probably cleaner, but I don't understand the downvote... The last of my three suggestions appears to be exactly the same code you gave, a switch could handle multiple specific codes, and a regex could filter the codes in any way. Sorry, I'm new (to answering) here. I am still learning what flies and what doesn't.